# Using nedb array for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, node-webkit

I'm new to angular and nedb. I'm trying to use an array from a nedb for ng-repeat.
I don't understand why my code don't work

```
   <div ng-repeat="hello in helloworld"></div>

...
 hellodb.find({}).sort({helloworld: 1}).exec(function (err, docs){
      $scope.helloworld = docs;
      console.log($scope.helloworld);
 });
```

If i do the same with a json file with the same content as the database

```
$http.get('helloworld.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.helloworld = data;
      console.log($scope.helloworld);
 });
```

the output in the console is the same, and ng-repeat works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `$scope.$apply()`? When you're calling some classic angular async function such as `$http.get()`, `$scope.$apply()` is called at the end automatically. I'm guessing that's the reason it works only in the second example of yours and not in the first. Try adding it after the assignment of `$scope.helloworld` in the callback. Read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's been bugging me for hours.. For future references it is $scope.$apply()